# Oracle client very slow to timeout after switching to Windows 10 (and changing provider in connection string)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-10, timeout, adodb

I'm currently porting a legacy VB6 application to Windows 10. It connects to an Oracle database (currently running Oracle 11g on the client). In order for this to work I had to update the provider in the connection string from "MSDAORA" to "ORAOLEDB.Oracle".

For the most part this works fine, but if I give the string a Data Source that doesn't exist (Which several of the tests do), then it takes a LONG time for it to time out and return an appropriate error message (e.g. ORA-12154 TNS could not resolve the connect identifier). This isn't just down to changing the provider as I can make the same change on Windows 7, and the timeout is a more reasonable 60 seconds or so.

Where can I configure these settings? The sqlnet.ora file is the same in both Win7 and Win10.

Here's a simple example of how I connect to the database:

```
Private Function OpenConn(databaseName As String) As ADODB.Connection

  Const cstrPROC As String = "OpenConn"
On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

#If TRACE And 1 Then
  Call OutputDebugString(cstrPROC & vbNewLine)
#End If
     
    Dim conDB As ADODB.Connection
    
    Set conDB = New ADODB.Connection
    
    With conDB
      '.CursorLocation = adUseClient
      
      Call .Errors.Clear
      Call .Open(Provider=ORAOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & databaseName, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
    End With

    Set OpenConn = conDB
  Exit Function

ErrorHandle:

  Call Err.Raise(Err.Number, , Err.Description)

End Function
```

Comment: Are you using / able to use Oracle Instant Client? https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html  What version of the client ODBC are you using?